# Why Xen requires an OS though it is a Type I Hypervisor?

Tags: virtualization, xen, hypervisor

Xen is a Type I hypervisor that means it can run directly on hardware so why do we need to install Ubuntu or CentOS or any OS to run Xen? It should run directly on the hardware as it's a Type I hypervisor.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that an OS is needed is because Xen itself does not directly provide any mechanism for creating/managing virtual machines. Because these tasks require things like creating disk images, editing configuration files, setting up networking etc. It would be wasteful for the Xen project to reimplement all of this functionality when it is already included in widely-used OSes like Linux.

The only way to interact with Xen is by making [hypercalls](https://wiki.xenproject.org/wiki/Hypercall), some of which can only be made from the [dom0 (Domain 0)](https://wiki.xenproject.org/wiki/Dom0) VM. As noted in the [Xen wiki](https://wiki.xenproject.org/wiki/Hypervisor) this means that the hypervisor can be left to just the tasks which only it can perform - checking page tables, allocating resources for new domains, and scheduling domains.

I'm not aware of any type 1 hypervisor which does not need an OS in one way or another - many of them use Xen under the hood, with a custom OS. Things like VMWare ESXi (which does not use Xen) bundle their own OS as part of the distribution so still have an OS running on top of the hypervisor to provide needed functionality.